# Do I have the option of adding or not adding an 's' to the word administration when it is already plural?

Tags: grammar, plural-forms, suffixes

Question: about ‘administration’ since it is singular and plural. Since the word is already plural, do I have the option of writing the last word as ‘administration’ or ‘administrations’
Sentence One: What was one issue debate between the parties during the Washington and Adams administrations?

Comment: "Administration" is not "already plural"; it *can* be uncountable, or mass.  That's not the same thing as being plural.  Did you check a dictionary for the various definitions of "administration"?

Answer (score 2):

"Administration" is a group noun, and like some other group nouns, it can have plural agreement when it is understood to refer to multiple individuals.

> Administration are unhappy with the productivity of the shopfloor workers.

The word "administration" has singular form but a plural meaning, and if we want to indicate that we are referring to the multiple individual people that make up the group, the plural agreement is possible.

However, as a collective, a singular agreement is more common:

> The Biden administration is unravelling four years of Trump orders.

The plural form would always refer to multiple instances of this singular meaning.

> The Bush, Obama and Trump administrations have all had to deal with crises.

You can't use the plural "administrations" to mean "multiple members of an administration team".  You can say "Administrators are unhappy..."

You must use the plural form when referring to several teams. You can't say "The Bush, Obama and Trump administration" unless you want to say that this is all the same team.

Answer (score -5):

Administration is an uncountable noun so it doesn't have a plural form with s.

Comment: How do you explain book titles like ["The Europeanisation of National Administrations"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Europeanisation_of_National_Administ/RfeqDxV-F3MC?hl=en&gbpv=0) then?

Comment: "Rain" is also an uncountable noun, but sometimes ["heavy rains](https://ludwig.guru/s/there+are+heavy+rains) is used.

Comment: LIke most uncountable nouns, _administration_ can be plural when it refers to particular instances or types. The countable and uncountable senses are not usually interchangeable.